# Порождение объектов с разными конструкторами

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ряд объектов (`SignInRequest`, `SignOutRequest` и т.д.), которые производны от одного абстрактного класса (`RequestBase`), но у всех этих объектов разные конструкторы, принимающие разное количество и тип аргументов.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как корректно организовать механизм порождения этих объектов? Имею ввиду, например фабрику или билдер или еще как-то.

```
abstract class RequestBase
{
}

class SignInRequest : RequestBase
{
    public SignInRequest(string userName)
    {
    }
}

class SignOutRequest : RequestBase
{
    public SignOutRequest()
    {
    }
}

class GetAllItemsRequest : RequestBase
{
    public GetAllItemsRequest(DateTime date, int someValue)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Поясните, что именно вы хотите от этого механизма порождения? Вы хотите написать [единую фабрику фабрик фабрик](https://habr.com/en/post/141477/)?

Comment: На самом деле, просто хочу совет, как правильно это сделать. Я новичок в программировании. Если для таких случаев есть какое-то проверенное решение - буду рад им воспользоваться. А если придется делать фабрику фабрик фабрик - то наверно, лучше будет вообще отказаться от такого "механизма".

Comment: "Если для таких случаев" - уточните, для каких случаев. У вас в голове видимо ясное представление случая, перед глазами проект -- но в вопросе об этом ни слова. По ссылке юмористическая статья о том, что попытка сделать универсальное решение всего (а это занимает бесконечное время и стоит бесконечных денег) смешна, но возможно вы скажете какой у вас сценарий и возможно есть какие-то типовые ходы. Мы не телепаты, в чужой мозг не заглянем -- поэтому вам надо как-то выгрузить словами ваш сценарий использования.

Comment: `как корректно организовать механизм порождения этих объектов` прежде, чем думать КАК что то сделать, подумайте, ЗАЧЕМ что то делать, какие у вас причины что то делать, какие у вас задачи, требующие создания этих объектов, какие критерии этих задач, какие требования к этим задачам, как понять, что тот или иной способ создания ваших объектов решает вашу задачу, и вот когда вы всё это поймете, тогда и спрашивайте, что конкретно выбрать и какие есть варианты. А пока ваш вопрос не несет никакого смысла, он ничего не решает.